# how to use the app pool account in a custom wcf service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application, wcf

Created a WCF service that is hosted in SharePoint and interacts with a SQL database. The site that I'm accessing the service from has kerberos enabled.

When I use the service, it is passing my credentials to SQL. How do I setup the web.config to pass the app pool account credentials to SQL?

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="customBasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="customBasicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="customBasicBehavior" name="blah.Services.s1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="customBasicHttpBinding"
    contract="blah.Services.Is1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try calling SQL using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. It should execute as app pool account.